# recursive commands for process children

Tags: c, recursion, tree, fork, wait

my code:

```
int i, pid;

int mainPid = getpid();

for(i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++) {
    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0) {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        printf("Child (%d): %d\n", i + 1, getpid());
        sleep(1);
        //SOME RECURSIVE FUNCTION FOR CHILD
        exit(0); 
    }
}


if(fork() == 0) {

    char a[100];
    sprintf(a, "%d", mainPid);
    execlp("pstree", "pstree", "-c", a, NULL);

}else { 
    sleep(1); 
}
```

and the output I get when parameter is 8, is:

```
Child (2): 3031
Child (7): 3036
Child (6): 3035
Child (1): 3030
Child (5): 3034
Child (8): 3037
Child (4): 3033
Child (3): 3032
t1─┬─pstree
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   └─t1
```

it is clear that children aren't in numeric order because some are born before others.

So my question is, is there a way to force that in numeric order becuase I would than like to call some kind of recursive function that would read a number from stdin and made that many children from first child proces and then read a nother number from stdin and made that many children from second child and so on... basically in the end, I would like to get something like this with calling pstree from main process:

```
   t1─┬─pstree
      ├─t1┬─t1
      |   └─t1
      ├─t1┬─t1─t1
      |   └─t1
      ├─t1
      ├─t1
      ├─t1─t1 
      └─t1
```

Comment: Unless you arrange for the children to synchronize themselves somehow, you can't control the scheduling reliably.

Comment: They are in order!  The pids are monotonically increasing with the children.  If you want to synchronize the children reading from stdin, your best bet is to let the parent do all the reading and pass the data to the children on pipes.

Comment: before this line: 'for(i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++) {'  there needs to be a check of 'argc' to assure it is (at least) 2, to assure there is a command line parameter to convert.  Also, the conversion only needs to be done once, so put the conversion before the 'for' statement and check that the resulting value is >0 to assure the parameter was a positive number

Answer (score 1):

It's quite an old question, still I thought good to answer:

I slightly tweaked your print statement as follows

```
for(i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++) {
    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0) {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        //printf("Child (%d): %d\n", i + 1, getpid());
        sleep(1);
        //SOME RECURSIVE FUNCTION FOR CHILD
        exit(0);
    } else {
        printf("Child (%d): %d\n", i + 1, pid);
    }
}

if(!(fork() == 0)) {

    char a[100];
    sprintf(a, "%d", mainPid);
    execlp("pstree", "pstree", "-c", a, NULL);

}else {
    sleep(1);
}
```

and I get what you expected (I believe):

```
Child (1): 10238
Child (2): 10239
Child (3): 10240
Child (4): 10241
Child (5): 10242
Child (6): 10243
Child (7): 10244
Child (8): 10245
pstree─┬─a.out
       ├─a.out
       ├─a.out
       ├─a.out
       ├─a.out
       ├─a.out
       ├─a.out
       ├─a.out
       └─a.out
```

Please let me know, if this is not what you have expected. Also, if you have already fixed it, how? :)